# No such payment Intent error stripe android integration

Tags: android, android-studio, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I followed this link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android After doing all steps when i do testing error occur,no such payment intent.

Comment: Hope you will get a soulution from here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/1942

Comment: @zinonX I tried this solution,but i didn't work for me

Comment: Almost certainly you're using API keys from different Stripe Accounts, or you're using Connect but not including the Stripe Account header somewhere that you should be (or are including it somewhere you shouldn't be).

Comment: @SAT did you find any fix for this problem ?

Comment: @Aswin.A.S yes,that was server key issue